# Java rotating counterclockwise 90 degrees

Tags: java

If I have a 2x2 image (with the following pixel colors below), and am rotating the pixels counterclockwise by 90 degrees, what would the new arrangement be?

```
{Pixel.BLACK, Pixel.BLUE},
{Pixel.RED, Pixel.GREEN}
```

I know this is a simple question, but my test case keeps on failing and I am guessing that perhaps my logic may be incorrect.

Comment: Are you simply asking for the resulting arrangement?

Comment: i figured it out, thanks though!

Comment: @user1993381 Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you or answers your question. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLUE, GREEN

BLACK, RED

If your coordinates were rows.